# Почему скрипт выполняется дважды?

Tags: javascript, jquery, webkit

Почему в браузерах на движке `webkit` этот скрипт выполняется два раза подряд? В других браузерах работает нормально

```
var jQ = false; 
function initJQ() {   
    if (typeof(jQuery) == 'undefined') {
        if (!jQ) {
            jQ = true;
            document.write('<scr' + 'ipt type="text/javascript" >  >     >src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.0.js"></scr' + 'ipt>');
        }
        setTimeout('initJQ()', 50);   
    } 
    else {
        (function($) {
            $(function() {
                 $("#reg-form").on('submit',function(){             
                    var arr = $('#reg-form').serializeArray();
                    var ok=true;            
                    $.ajax({
                        url:'index.php?option=com_admin&task=ajaxValidate',
                        type:'post',
                        async:false,
                        data:{'reg_data':arr},
                        success:function(resp)
                        {   
                            if(resp=='done')
                            {
                                return true;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                $('#alert').show();
                                ok=false; 
                            }
                        }           
                    }); 
                    if(!ok)
                        return false;
                })
            })
        })(jQuery)   
    } 
} 
initJQ();
```

Comment: Может быть потому, что функция внутри себя вызывается ещё раз?

Comment: эм, где именно?

Comment: setTimeout('initJQ()', 50);   
здесь

Comment: Мне кажется надо по другому организовать, а не  

    document.write('<scr' + 'ipt type="text/javascript" >  >     >src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.0.js"></scr' + 'ipt>');

Comment: это динамическое подключение библиотеки jquery, я спрашиваю про обработку onsubmit формы

Answer (score 2, accepted):

За 50мс не успевает загрузиться jQuery (или еще какая-нить проблема из-за таймаута), в результате хэндлер onsubmit ставится два или более раз.

Устанавливайте onload хэндлер.

```
var script=document.createElement('script');
script.src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.0.js';
document.head.appendChild(script);
script.onload=initJQ;
```

вместо

```
if (!jQ) {
    jQ = true;
    document.write('<scr' + 'ipt type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.0.js"></scr' + 'ipt>');
}
setTimeout('initJQ()', 50);
```

не полагайтесь на время - оно ненадежно.

конечный вариант такой примерно должен быть:

```
function initJQ() {
    if (typeof (jQuery) == 'undefined') {
        var script = document.createElement('script');
        script.src = 'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.0.js';
        document.head.appendChild(script); 
        script.onload = runJQ; //другая функция, чтобы незациклиться

    } else runJQ();

    function false_ret() {
        return false;
    }

    function runJQ() {
        jQuery(function ($) {
            var $reg_form = $("#reg-form");

            function error_trigger() {
                $reg_form.unbind('submit.myns'); //убираем return false
                $reg_form.one('submit', checkform); //возвращаем хэндлер проверки
                $('#alert').show();
            }

            function checkform() {
                $reg_form.bind('submit.myns',false_ret); //не даем сабмитить еще раз,
                                            // до окончания запроса, 
                                            // используем namespace myns, 
                                            // чтобы не перекрыть другие хэндлеры submit
                var arr = $reg_form.serializeArray();                    
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'index.php?option=com_admin&task=ajaxValidate',
                    type: 'post',
                    async: true, //делаем асинхронно, синхронно - плохо
                    data: {
                        'reg_data': arr
                    },
                    success: function (resp) {
                        if (resp == 'done') {
                            $reg_form.unbind('submit.myns'); //убираем return false
                            $reg_form.submit(); //всё хорошо. отправляем форму
                            return true;
                        } else {
                            error_trigger();
                        }
                    },
                    error: error_trigger
                });
                return false; //не сабмитим до проверки
            }
            $reg_form.one('submit', checkform); //один раз
        });
    }
}
initJQ();
```

[демо](http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/72zaN/)

Answer (score 0):

Устанавливайте таймаут правильно:

```
setTimeout(initJQ, 50);
```

А еще можете объяснить для чего так организован код ниже?

```
(function($) {
    $(function() {
        /* code here */
    })
})(jQuery)
```

Comment: а в чем разница?

Comment: и вообще, я имею ввиду, что два раза срабатывает ajax запрос

Comment: код так организован, чтобы от $ не зависеть я полагаю, абсолютный эквивалент:
jQuery(function($) {
        /* code here */
    });